# Sequelize belongsToMany validation error

Tags: node.js, sqlite, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm facing a problem since 3 days. I would like to create a **multiple relation n:m** in **Sequelize** but I'm getting an error message : "*Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error*".

So I have 3 tables :

- Serie.
- Episode.
- Season (in this table I would like to add relation to **Serie** and **Episode**).

**Here is the definition of Serie :**

```
var Serie = sequelize.define('Serie', {
      idSerie: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
      },
      name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
```

**Episode :**

```
var Episode = sequelize.define('Episode', {
      idEpisode: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
      },
      description: DataTypes.TEXT
    }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
```

**And Season :**

```
var Season = sequelize.define('Season', {
        idSeason: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        numero: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        idEpisode: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        idSerie: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            // associations can be defined here

            models.Episode.belongsToMany(models.Serie, { through: models.Season, foreignKey: 'idEpisode', otherKey:'idSerie' });
            models.Serie.belongsToMany(models.Episode, { through: models.Season, foreignKey: 'idSerie', otherKey:'idEpisode' });
      }
    }
  });
```

**To add a new relation I used this :**

```
// serieFound was fetched using findOne and newEpisode was created
serieFound.addEpisode(newEpisode);
```

PS: I'm using **sequelize-cli** to create DB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Do you predict a situation where the same episode is assign to the same serie twice? Maybe that's the case

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by assigning twice ? Same object ?

Comment: For example if you assign `Episode` with `idEpisode: 1` to the same serie twice (like `serieFound.addEpisode(1)` called twice).

Comment: Oh ok, nop addEpisode() is called just one time :/

Comment: On the log, here is the last SQL query : INSERT INTO `Seasons` (`idSeason`,`idEpisode`,`idSerie`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,1,1,'2017-03-16 19:49:21.243 +00:00','2017-03-16 19:49:21.243 +00:00');