# How to generate fake records in a relation N-M in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have two tables: `User` and `Scope`; with the cardinality of N (`User`) -> M (`Scope`). When I insert fake records inside the `User` and the `Scope` tables, everything goes well, but if I insert fake records (ids from the `User` and `Scope` tables) inside the `UserScope` relation table, which represents the relation between `User` and `Scope`, I receive the errors:

1:

```sh
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
```

2:

```sh
Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`graph`.`userScope`, CONSTRAINT 'userScope_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY (`scopeId`) REFERENCES `scope` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I had tried to debug via MySQL console (`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`):

```sh
CONSTRAINT 'userScope_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('scopeId') REFERENCES 'scope' ('id') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
Trying to add in child table, in index userScope_userId_scopeId_unique tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 3 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 80000008; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 8000000a; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

But in parent table 'graph'. 'scope', in index PRIMARY,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 696e66696d756d00; asc infimum ;;
```

And I had found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829460/sequelize-belongstomany-validation-error) question that makes me think that the way I'm inserting data in the relation table is not right, i.g, duplicate relations are being added in the relation table.

I'm inserting the relations this way:

```
import db from "./models";

import faker from "faker";

import times from "lodash.times";

import random from "lodash.random";

const amount = 10;

db.user.bulkCreate(
  times(amount, () => ({
    email: faker.internet.email(),
    password: faker.internet.password(),
    name: `${faker.name.firstName} ${faker.name.lastName}`,
    birth: Date.now()
  }))
)

db.scope.bulkCreate(
  times(amount, () => ({
    title: faker.hacker.verb()
  }))
)

db.userScope.bulkCreate(
  times(amount, () => ({
    scopeId: random(1, amount),
    userId: random(1, amount)
  }))
);
```

The tables:

[image]

[image]

I expect to insert fake relations in the `UserScope` table, without any errors and in a random way.

Obs: I had set the `amount` to `1` / set manually the ids and I still receiving this error. I had also already read threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709409/unhandled-rejection-sequelizeuniqueconstrainterror-validation-error) one, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) one but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases that can cause the problem:

1. A field has the constraint `unique` and the rows have duplicated values, for the `unique` field
2. A table reference another table that don't have reverential integrity constraints
3. The rows values of the reference table don't match some of the referenced key values
4. The data type of the primary keys are different, e.g MySQL sometimes convert the types in a different way for the same data type

My case is the first one. I was using the `random` function of [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#random) and the functions of [Faker](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/), but none of the available functions helped me. I researched and found [Chance](https://github.com/chancejs/chancejs), but again this had not helped, so I write my script for generate random values and use it in a way that they don't repeat:

```
const randomNumbers = (length, start=1) => {
  let array = [...Array(length).keys()].map(value => start + value);

  array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

  return array;
};

export { randomUniqueNumbers };
```

In the models:

```
// ...

import { randomUniqueNumbers } from "./util";

let scopeIds = randomUniqueNumbers(length);

let userIds = randomUniqueNumbers(length);

db.userScope
  .bulkCreate(
    times(length, () => ({
      scopeId: scopeIds.pop(),
      userId: userIds.pop()
    }))
  )
  .then(userScope => {})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

My project on [Github](https://github.com/Sphinxs/Graph).

The relations:

[image]

To test the N-M relation I had add another row in the relation table to prove that one scope can be used for one or more users:

```
INSERT INTO userScope(createdAt, updatedAt, scopeId, userId) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('18,05,2019','%d,%m,%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('18,05,2019','%d,%m,%Y'), 1, 1);
```

**Obs**: If you don't like the Graph QL + Sequelize + Node, I recommend the [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) package.

**Obs ²**: Apply the same idea for the other tables that has `unique` fields

**Obs ³**: Another option is to implement your own function that uses the concept of seed, like Numpy Random

References:

[Cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143651/cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

[MySQL error 1452](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

[Foreign key](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/)

[Unique](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/)

[Sequelize belongs to many](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html)

[Foreign key MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)